# Is there a quick way to get the raw values of all performance counters rather than setting each one up individually?

Tags: c#

When using performance counters, is there a way to get all the counters (and their related data) on my local machine rather than setting up each counter individually, like so:

```
cntr.Category = "";
string Result = cntr.NextValue.ToString();

[...Lines ommitted...]
```

Obviously the above is not very practical when working with 50+ counters.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience working with the managed wrappers is not feasible for real monitoring. For any serious volume I found that it took just way too long time to iterate through the individual PerformanceCounter instances.

What I ended up was use p-Invoke into the native high performance counters library, [PDH.DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373214(VS.85).aspx):

- [Collecting Performance Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371897(VS.85).aspx)
- [Writing Performance Data to a Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373228(VS.85).aspx)
- [Reading Performance Data from a Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373169(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods GetCategories() and GetCounters() of the [PerformanceCounterCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory_members.aspx) class to get all existing counters of each category.